# how to utilize openssl (already integrated with kernel) with openvpn?

Tags: openssl, openvpn, embedded-system

the Embedded linux kernel is generated with openssl

so i want to use this openssl with the other application eg. openvpn  rather than compiling openssl and using it with openvpn

just so that hardware acceleration for openssl can be used

but i don't get how to do it

Thanks in advance

Comment: you've got a basic misunderstanding of how libraries, kernel/process interaction and hardware acceleration work.

Comment: I agree. This is a XY-problem post. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

Hardware acceleration can and will be used by openssl if the processor supports it (i.e. AES-NI or similar). There is no need to move the crypto functionality  inside the kernel for these since these CPU instructions are usable from user space too, similar to almost all other CPU instructions.

Comment: jep, doing a context switch to kernel land to do some crypto sounds like it would make crypto a lot *slower* instead of faster. There's no good reason for letting the kernel do crypto for userland.